# Adding a summary column to a Reporting Services matrix

Tags: reporting-services

How can I set up a Matrix on a Reporting Services 2000 report so that the last column is a sum of the values of the row?

Edit: just to be clear, I don't need a summary of rows, I need one at the end of each column.

Something like:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 Total 
1    2    3    6
2    0    5    7 
1    1    1    3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer, but I'm not sure I understand the logic behind it.

You can right-click the header column and select "subtotal" to create a subtotal column. My problem was that this did not show the correct values, it showed the field values of the first column, go figure.

After some voodoo and ritual sacrificing of two goats, I managed to discover that if you change the value of the field to Sum(field), then the subtotal is displayed correctly and so is the field... weird stuff

So, summary:

```
Col1   Col2   Col3   Total
Field1 Field2 Field3 Subtotal
```

yielded:

```
Col1   Col2   Col3    Total
1      2      3        1
2      0      5        2
1      1      1        1
```

but changing the field definition to Sum(Field3) instead of Field3 gave me the correct result.